# Showing that a sequence is Cauchy on $C[0,1]$.

Tags: functional-analysis, complete-spaces

Let $$f_k(t) = \begin{cases}0, \text{ if } t \in [0,1/2]\\
1, \text{ if } t \in [1/2 + 1/k, 1].\end{cases}$$We will prove the sequence $(f_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy on $(C[0,1],\|\cdot\|_p)$ for $1 \leq p < \infty$. (this can also be done for $\infty$ but for the sake of the exercise we shall omit that case). Notice that \begin{align}
\|f_n-f_n\|_p & = \left(\int_0^1|f_n(t)-f_m(t)|^pdt\right)^{1/p}\\
& \leq 2\left(\int_{1/2+1/n}^1|f_n(t)|^pdt - \int_{1/2 + 1/m}^1|f_m(t)|^pdt\right)^{1/p}\\
& \leq 2\left(\int_{1/2+1/n}^1dt - \int_{1/2+1/m}^1dt\right)^{1/p}\\
& \leq 2\left(1-1/2-1/n - 1 + 1/2 + 1/m\right)^{1/p}\\
& = 2\left(\frac{1}{m} - \frac{1}{n}\right)^{1/p}.
\end{align}And when $n,m \rightarrow \infty$ we have $\|f_n-f_m\| \rightarrow 0$. Rigorously, we could pick $N > 0$ so that when choosing $n>m\geq N$ we have $1/m-1/n < \epsilon$.

Can anyone verify if my reasoning is correct? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Presumably, $f_k$ is defined on $[1/2,1/2+1/k]$ by linearly interpolating, right? How did you get the first inequality?

Comment: @Stewan, Indeed, we connect 0 to 1 with a line along the interval. The first inequality results from $(a+b)^p \leq 2^p(|a|^p + |b|^p)$. But now I see that I need to account for that interval $[1/2,1/2+1/k]$ and I have not in my solution.

Comment: @Stewan I found another error in the proof. Namely, that when I split both integrals it must be a plus instead of minus.

Comment: I'm a bit confused because we look at $C([a,b])$, but define $f_k$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Matija, my mistake. Let me correct it to $[0,1]$. However I believe we can extend it to any $[a,b]$ by doing the necessary adjustments on the definition of $f_k$

Comment: Sure, that wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the functions $f_k$ are continuous and somewhere in $[0,1]$ on $[1/2,1/2+1/k]$. Then we have
\begin{align*}
\|f_n-f_m\|_p^p=\int_{1/2}^{1/2+1/N}|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|^p\mathrm dx
\le\int_{1/2}^{1/2+1/N}1^p\mathrm dx
=\frac{1}{N}
\end{align*}
for $n\ge m\ge N$, where we used that $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\le 1$ since $f_n(x),f_m(x)\in[0,1]$, and that $x^p$ is increasing for $x\ge 0$. So, for any $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$ we take $N=\varepsilon^{-p}$, then we get $\|f_n-f_m\|_p\le\varepsilon$ for all $n,m\ge N$, so the sequence is Cauchy.

Comment: It makes sense but what did you do to the integration on $[1/2 + 1/M, 1]$?

Comment: For $x\in[1/2+1/N,1]$ we have $f_n(x)=f_m(x)=1$ since $x\ge 1/2+1/N\ge 1/2+1/m\ge 1/2+1/n$ using $n\ge m\ge N$. Hence, we have $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|=0$.

Comment: Oh, it cancels each other!! thank you very much for your answer!